# accessing HashMap data from a nested HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have an interesting situation here. I am building a board game and I have a board declared that is of HashMap

```
HashMap<String, HashMap> board = new HashMap<String, HashMap>();
```

There are multiple layers on this board, and this is why this HashMap must take other HashMaps.

We populate this board with tile objects, as following.

```
HashMap tileObject = new HashMap();
tileObject.put("key1", value1);
tileObject.put("key2", value2);
tileObject.put("name", value3);
```

We are adding this (and other tiles) to the board.

```
board.put((String)tileObject.get("name"), tileObject);
```

So that's all good and dandy, we have added tiles to the board. Now my issue is, reading from this board. When analyzing the board I have this snippet of code in a function

```
HashMap takeTileObject = new HashMap();
takeTileObject.put("unique-coordinate", board.get("unique-coordinate");
// we are getting the values from board at key "unique-coordinate"
```

what I need to do is access key1/key2/name from takeTileObject. I have tried this

```
takeTileObject.get("unique-coordinate").(NOTHING HELPFUL HERE);
```

What I would ideally like to happen is something like this.

```
takeTileObject.get("unique-coordinate").get("key1");
```

is this possible?

Thank you greatly for any help in advance.

Comment: it varies. In the code it has both integers and strings. Name itself is a string, there are x and y coordinates which are integers, a few status effects which are boolean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because didn't specify the type of `takeTileObject`

```
HashMap<String, HashMap> takeTileObject = new HashMap<String, HashMap>();
```

Tell the system that the value is a HashMap object and you should able to call it

```
takeTileObject.get("unique-coordinate").get("key1");
```

Comment: and just like that, my savior waltz in and saves the day :). Thank you so much! This worked perfectly.

Comment: ...and by the way, maybe MultiMap in Google Collections code can be useful intead of implementing a map of maps [http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html).

Answer (score 0):

Change ths piece of code

```
HashMap(String, HashMap> board = new HashMap<String, HashMap>();
```

to

```
HashMap<String, HashMap> board = new HashMap<String, HashMap>();
```